# How to revert Google Chrome context menu back to Windows style

Tags: google-chrome

I just right clicked on a text in Google Chrome and found that the total menu structure has changed. This started with version 26.0.1410.*.

It is not just the context menu but all of its context menus are the same. It has more padding and does not look like a Windows style menu.

How can we revert back to the old context menu style.

I have got used to the distances of each option in the context menu and now I feel like I am doing a rheumatic exercise for my wrist.

Here is a screen shot:

[image: menu]

Comment: Up voted because I'm interested if it's possible. I don't really mind the new context menus at all.

Comment: To me it is important that the GUI on my computer is consistent, for aesthetical reasons. Currently, 'all' my Windows applications use the standard Win32 menus, except for Google Chrome, which has its own menus. That's not beautiful.

Comment: ...and there goes the Win32-styled scrollbars.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Go to shorcut **properties** and add `--disable-new-menu-style` flag (with a space) to **Target** field.
Now Chrome starts with old context menu. Unpin other Chrome shorcuts and pin again.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-new-menu-style - it worked... how to do it from chrome...

Comment: when ever i start chrome i use run to type 'chrome' so that i don't have to use the mouse and again comeback to the keyboard to type in the url... let me find a way for that.

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore.... :-( (see here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chrome/lHMXuSbRo4c )

Comment: This command-line switch is removed from Chrome and (sadly) it's in stable now.

Comment: I can also confirm that as of Chrome 28 this workaround no longer works. Damn, I really can't get used to that padding.

Comment: Ugly as hell with the new menu styling! Thought with the update they would have given you the option to disable it now that they have broken the --disable.. trick

Comment: I'm running `30.0.1599.10` on the `dev` branch and they've reduced the near-hideous padding to the point where I now prefer it over the standard windows context menu. http://i.imgur.com/WAVSgyo.png

Comment: In 32, they removed this option completely.

Answer (score 2):

This thread treats the problem :
[How can I bring back the old menu style on Chrome 28 onwards, now that the --disable-new-menu-style switch has been removed?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/a1HEE-7bjlA%5B1-25-true%5D)

It says that Google has [made clear](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/a1HEE-7bjlA%5B1-25-true%5D) that they've made an arbitrary decision to do this and aren't interested in revisiting it.

The workaround for
Chrome 28.0.1500.72 (Official Build 211400) is the following switch which
activates a new style with much less vertical padding:

> --force-fieldtrials="NewMenuStyle/Compact2/"

This unfortunately also has the effect of collapsing the row of extension icons.

Answer (score -6):

- Uninstall Chrome.
- Find an old version you like (See [OldApps](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php))
- Never update again

You may lose features like sync at some point when Google changes protocol. Software is always an evolving thing. You could submit a feature request to Google.

Also since Chromium is open-source you could download it and patch it yourself.

Comment: if the above is not going to work in future then i am going to follow your option. this is what i do with most softwares. :)

Comment: -1 - Why would you recommend a user revert to an older release which is potentially vulnerable, given Chrome's regular security updates?  Further, Chrome auto-updates and you've made no mention of how to disable that so anyone following your suggestion would have a current browser almost immediately anyway.

Comment: I also recommended he could download the source and modify it :). There are tons of requests on this site where someone doesn't like a new feature. I am glad in this case there was a switch for him but that's usually not the case. Usually your only option is to run an older version if you really care about a feature that is removed.

Comment: _"Find an old version [...] Never update again"_ - your suggestion is simply ridiculous. You suggest something that could be VERY harmful and dangerous, and which goes against common sense. For example, think about the people who don't upgrade their [Internet Explorer versions](http://threatpost.com/ie-8-zero-day-found-as-dol-watering-hole-attack-spreads-to-nine-other-sites/). We're talking about a **browser** here...

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I was being somewhat facetious. The reality is that the UI changes with most new software releases and most times there isn't a flag to control it (eg. don't like the ribbon stay on Office 2003).

Comment: @BradPatton: as I've already mentioned, we're talking about a browser, not a software which is mostly used offline (yes, it's not even completely true for Office 2003...). It can be a huge **security risk** NOT to update and old browser. I think you'd better delete your "answer" before you get more downvotes. The other answer with the `--disable-new-menu-style` switch solves the problem, but your answer only contains a possibly really harmful suggestion.