# Chromium menu padding too large

Tags: linux, browser, linux-mint, context-menu, chromium

I am running Linux Mint 13 Maya (LTS)

I have recently updated my `Chromium` to 37.0.2062.94 from official repository. New menus absolutely ruin usability with oversized padding between items. This applies to Chromium Menu, all context menus and bookmark dropdown lists.

Screenshot:

[image]

I have already seen these two threads:

- [How to disable new spacing when right clicking in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/579247/281154)
- [How to revert Google Chrome context menu back to Windows style](https://superuser.com/q/578704/281154)

But both seem to suggest solution that works or used to work under Windows but don't helpin my case.

adding `--disable-new-menu-style` as a startup argument does not change anything. According to [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259531) this parameter has been removed.
I have also tried `--force-fieldtrials="NewMenuStyle/Compact2/"` with no luck

Any suggestions how to get normal menus back?

Comment: I think this has been improved in version 38. This [thread](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-google-chrome-38-unstable-on-the-most-popular-linux-systems-via-the-official-google-repository/) might help.

Comment: @harrymc, I can confirm that the context menu appearance has been improved significantly in version 38. The link you provided helped me to install version 38 (beta) and I am very happy with it so far. If yo u would care to post this as an answer, then I could mark it as accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs in the current stable version of Chromium, version 37, and is
basically a GUI bug.

Some improvements has been done in the current unstable version of Google Chrome,
version 38.

If you wish to install the unstable version, see this article:

[How To Install Google Chrome 38 (Unstable) On The Most Popular Linux Systems, Via The Official Google Repository](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-google-chrome-38-unstable-on-the-most-popular-linux-systems-via-the-official-google-repository/).