# How to change the new format of context menu in Chrome to be like the old one?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, context-menu, chromium

The new Chrome version from a few days ago doesn't show all elements of the context menu at once anymore. Instead, it shows only some of them, and I have to scroll to see the others. How can I make it show all elements, like in earlier versions?

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/814723/chromium-menu-padding-too-large) and [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/lgqdt7/drop_down_menu_too_large_again/) say that the solutions `--disable-new-menu-style` and `--force-fieldtrials="NewMenuStyle/Compact2/"` don't work anymore.

By the way, the size of the context menu (number of visible elements) depends on where I click.

(Also bookmarks now have too small menus, too large font, and too much spacing. A solution for that is welcome as well.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Go to `chrome://flags/`.
- Search for `#chrome-refresh-2023` - not the others with more text after 2023.
- Disable it.
- **Edit:**

  - Also disable `#customize-chrome-side-panel` - not the other one with more text.

    - (Backstory: the original solution stopped working this week, but the description of the aforementioned flag said "Customize Chrome Side Panel must also be enabled [for the new, bad Chrome design to work]", indicating the new solution.)
  - Apparently in some cases it's necessary to also disable "Chrome WebUI Refresh 2023", see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1bjftpa/hate_the_latest_chrome_desktop_ui_revert_back/)
- Restart Chrome and feel at ease again, pray they keep this flag.
- **This solution will probably stop working in a few months, unless you send feedback to Google as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1bjftpa/hate_the_latest_chrome_desktop_ui_revert_back/)**

Comment: Thank you! Does this also also undo performance improvements that seem to have been rolled out at the same time?

Comment: Giacomo1968 sorry for any spam, this is my first post, as I just wanted to help the guy out after finding this post and others via Google.
I had some issues getting new lines to work, so I tried a lot of things, including editing and making several new lines and spaces after each line to finally making it easy to read.

Comment: @root You're welcome, I don't know about the performance, but there are other similar new 2023 flags you may want to look into.

Comment: Did not work for me as of Jan 15, 2024

Comment: This _did_ work for me, but with **severe side effects**. I was concerned that I'd lose the recent tab style enhancement (big group dots), but that's still there. The tab list dropdown (top left) is gone, though. I wonder what else is gone from the [15th birthday refresh](https://blog.google/products/chrome/google-chrome-new-features-redesign-2023/).

Comment: Shadi are you 100% sure you disabled the right flag? This has been working for everyone else.

Comment: Seems the problem is back again since a new update.

Comment: @roman204 yes, now it is also necessary to disable the flag 'Customize Chrome Side Panel', and some need to disable the flag 'Chrome WebUI Refresh 2023', with the same procedure as originally.


More details here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1bjftpa/hate_the_latest_chrome_desktop_ui_revert_back/


Thanks a lot Google!! .........